# Getting wrong colors after converting to byte array

Tags: c#

After converting my image to byte array I get strange colors.
It should look like this:

[image]

But it looks like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    int t1 = Environment.TickCount;
    var o = System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
    RectangleF r1 = imageIn.GetBounds(ref o);
    Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle((int)r1.X, (int)r1.Y, (int)r1.Width, (int)r1.Height);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData omg = ((Bitmap)imageIn).LockBits(r2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    byte[] rgbValues = new byte[r2.Width * r2.Height * 4];
    Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)omg.Scan0, rgbValues, 0, rgbValues.Length);
    ((Bitmap)imageIn).UnlockBits(omg);
    return rgbValues;
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Image 1 RGB maps to Image 2 BGR. So it looks like you need to change from RGBA to BGRA

Comment: Thank you man i love you hahahah. i was struggling with this for 30 minutes, and now you helped me in few seconds! Thank so much, have a good day!

Comment: You're welcome :) You too